# Effect of SEO on Mixed Language Content in a Single page

Tags: seo, google-search, multilingual, technical-seo

I want to know what will happen, if I prepare a single page content in two languages. For example English & Hindi content in same page. Main keywords are in English. By considering Google can translate the Hindi content to English, will they able to show this page in search results ? Or it will affect badly?

Answer (score 1):

It probably will negatively affect your SEO.

Here is why:

Page titles and meta description have small character limits. This means the title and meta description can only conceivably have 1 language in them.

A title can have 55-60 characters.
https://searchengineland.com/title-tag-length-388468.

A meta description has 120 characters mobile or 155 desktop. https://www.brightedge.com/glossary/meta-description

What this means is that you'd have to pick a language to show for your search results.  In the below image the title text is in blue, whereas the meta description is on black text for each search results.

[image: example of a search results page]

This is basically your free advertisement that google lets you give to people searching for a term on the web that describes what is on your page. Now if a user visits a website who's title and meta description are in English and most of the page is in Spanish, only the people that speak both languages will be able to read it.

In the above scenario most users would have a bad user experience and leave your website. Google would in turn refer less traffic in the future to you as a result of the poor user experience on the page.

Now if for example, you have one part of the page in English and that same text translated into Spanish you would probably not have your page penalized, but, you'd be missing out on the opportunity to target the phrase in 2 languages and get the traffic for that term in each language. By having 2 pages, one on each language, you gain the ability to target the same term, but in two different languages.

For example, in English you could target, "Cruise ship vacations". You'd make a title saying, "Browse Luxury Cruise Ship Vacations Today". You'd make a meta description saying, "View our luxury cruise ship vacations with Carnival, Holland America and other prominent lines today!"

You could make a second page in Spanish to target the phrase, "vacaciones en crucero". You'd have a title saying, "Explore vacaciones en cruceros de lujo hoy!" You'd have a meta description saying, "¡Vea nuestras vacaciones en cruceros de lujo con Carnival, Holland America y otras líneas destacadas hoy!"

By having two pages you'd gain traffic in both languages all while having a better user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Using English and Hindi simultaneously in the same content is against **[Google's policy for multilingual websites](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/specialty/international/managing-multi-regional-sites?hl=en#make-sure-the-page-language-is-obvious)**:

> Make sure the page language is obvious